# save wmic useraccount where name to variable

Tags: batch-file, wmic, sid

How can I save the SID of the current user to variable?
Based off of a similar question, the current code is as follows:

```
@echo off
for /f %%a in ('wmic useraccount where Name='%username%' get SID') do set "usersid=%%a"
echo %usersid%
exit /b
```

Is there a way I can save this to the variable %usersid%?
I believe this is an issue with the '' marks surrounding %username%.

Answer (score 3):

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%a in (`wmic useraccount  where Name^='%username%' get SID /format:value`) do (
  for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ("%%a") do set "%%#"
)
set sid
```

On my machine I have no username alias.[Here's why the additional FOR is needed](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4266)

Comment: Hey npocmaka, when I run your code, I get an error stating the the environment variable sid is not define. Would this be the set sid line?

Comment: @7thLuke - what is the output of the command `wmic username where Name='%username%' get SID /format:value`

Comment: username - Alias not found.
I think we need to use wmic useraccount where name='%username%' get SID

Answer (score 3):

I found an answered question with the code required to do this.
Npocmaka was close to the answer (had I not incorrectly typed my original wmic command).

```
@echo off
for /f "delims= " %%a in ('"wmic useraccount where name='%UserName%' get sid"') do (
   if not "%%a"=="SID" (          
      set myvar=%%a
      goto :loop_end
   )   
)

:loop_end
echo %myvar%
```

Answer (score 0):

I have simplified the code provided by 7th Luke.

```
@echo off
For /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%# in (
'"wmic useraccount where name="%UserName%" get SID /value"') Do (
echo  %%#) & Pause > nul
```